Diff was suppressed because of file size or pattern
When I select a revision in the file history, it does not show the diff instead saying

Diff was suppressed because of file size or pattern

How do I show the diff?
In my SourceTree preferences for "Diff" I have Size Limit (text) set to 524,288 KB.  The "Visual Diff Tool" is set to FileMerge.
The file is a under 18KB
> wc Gemfile.lock
705    1878   17894 Gemfile.lock

The change using the command line show this as my diff:
> git diff a9e35bd1d..661d3b263
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index 936292302..3f1ca429d 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -245,6 +245,7 @@ GEM
     faraday-patron (1.0.0)
     faraday-rack (1.0.0)
     faraday-retry (1.0.3)
+    ffi (1.17.0)
     ffi (1.17.0-x86_64-darwin)
     ffi-compiler (1.3.2)
       ffi (>= 1.15.5)
@@ -369,6 +370,7 @@ GEM
       nokogiri (~> 1)
       rake
     mini_mime (1.1.5)
+    mini_portile2 (2.8.7)
     minitest (5.25.1)
     multi_json (1.15.0)
     multi_test (1.1.0)
@@ -394,6 +396,9 @@ GEM
       net-protocol
     net-ssh (5.0.2)
     nio4r (2.7.3)
+    nokogiri (1.15.4)
+      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.2)
+      racc (~> 1.4)
     nokogiri (1.15.4-x86_64-darwin)
       racc (~> 1.4)
     notiffany (0.1.3)
@@ -579,6 +584,7 @@ GEM
     zeitwerk (2.6.18)

 PLATFORMS
+  amd64-freebsd-13
   x86_64-darwin-21
   x86_64-darwin-23

File Magic recognizes the file as ASCII.
> file Gemfile.lock
Gemfile.lock: ASCII text

